# Class not found in Google Cloud app

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am getting the following **error:**

> Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient' not found in /base/data/home/apps/e~brookes-room-usage/1.3998538263957262‌​38/record-usage.php on line 84

so presumably I have failed to point my app correctly to that class.

I have enabled the Datastore API on the cloud console.

I have tried to find documentation relating to how to set up a PHP connection to the Datastore API.

I tried to [create a settings.yml file using the instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) but I didn't know what my client ID or my client secret were.

```
# Google credentials and configuration
google_client_id:      YOUR_CLIENT_ID
google_client_secret:  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
google_project_id:     YOUR_PROJECT_ID

# options are "cloudsql", "mongodb", or "datastore"
bookshelf_backend: datastore
```

([source on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/blob/master/2-structured-data/config/settings.yml.dist))

**What do I need to get my PHP app on Google Cloud to recognise `Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient` and connect to the Datastore API so that I can retrieve and post data?**

Comment: OK, got the settings.yml file written properly using these instructions. https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/authenticate-users
Do I need anything else?

Comment: do I need to install Composer?

Comment: so it turns out that you can only run PHP with Datastore on a Google Cloud app on your local device, not on Google Appengine, unless you use a third-party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that you can only run PHP with Datastore on a Google Cloud app on your local device, not on Google Appengine, unless you use a third-party library.

Which is why I am now writing my app in Python instead.

(**Update**: this may no longer be the case. This answer was written in 2017.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to include `google/cloud-datastore` library. Install via composer as below.

`$ composer require google/cloud-datastore`

and you can use  as below.

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;

$datastore = new DatastoreClient([
    'projectId' => 'my_project'
]);

// Create an entity
$bob = $datastore->entity('Person');
$bob['firstName'] = 'Bob';
$bob['email'] = 'bob@example.com';
$datastore->insert($bob);

// Update the entity
$bob['email'] = 'bobV2@example.com';
$datastore->update($bob);

// If you know the ID of the entity, you can look it up
$key = $datastore->key('Person', '12345328897844');
$entity = $datastore->lookup($key);
```

More details: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php#google-cloud-datastore-ga
I am already using this and working fine for me.